# Will mysql version change affect migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-migration

I want to transfer my Ruby on Rails project to another platform.

Currently my RDS is running over mySQL 5.5 which is discontinued, will it be ok to utilize mySQL 5.7 instead and will database migration be affected? 
What could be consequences?

Comment: I would argue this depends entirely on your application. You application might run fine on both versions or it not even run. I recommend reviewing the documentation about [What is New in MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html) and [in MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html). And for each change feature or change default, you have to check your application if it uses that feature or depends on certain behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql does not support direct upgrade skipping versions, so you'll have to upgrade in steps: 5.5->5.6->5.7, and then, maybe, 8 (actually, sometimes for simple databases a 5.5->5.7 jump might work, but it is not guaranteed and you may loose data).

1. make a backup
2. You need to have compatible `mysql2` gem version (fresh enough)
3. See MySQL changes([5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html) and [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html)) and corresponding upgrade [guides](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrade-paths.html) to:

   - make your app compatible (replace deprecated/removed features, adapt for new defaults etc.)
   - migrate data and mysql itself (if your database is big or under constant load, logical dumping+loading might not be acceptable), usually it involves upgrading to most recent patch version and then jumping to next version, sometimes running mysql migration tool
4. plan for a downtime (in worst case - a backup restore)

To minimize downtime - you can make use of mysql's ability to create a mixed-version cluster (add 5.6 slave to your present 5.5 master, then promote in to master, and so on)